# Magento: transfer product to customer's cart android

Tags: android, magento, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I am making shopping cart using android ksoap2  and magento soap api V2. I am unable to move the cart products to customer's cart using the api shoppingCartProductMoveToCustomerQuote. I am getting error as 'Customer’s quote is not existed'.I used the [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cartProduct.html)

I have use the code below:

```
    private String response,id;
      String[][] Products = new String[][] {{"20","20","1"}};
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
           {
            try
            {
              //SoapEnvelop.VER11 is SOAP Version 1.1 constant
              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);  
              envelope.dotNet = true;
              envelope.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
              envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"login");
              request.addProperty("username", "***");
              request.addProperty("apiKey", "*********");

              //envelope.bodyOut = request;
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
              try 
              {
                 transport.debug=true;
                 transport.call(NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX + "shoppingCartProductAdd", envelope);
//                transport.call(NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX + "catalogProductList", envelope);

                 response=(String) envelope.getResponse();
                 String sessionId = response.toString();
                 Log.d("The session Id is:",sessionId);

              SoapObject SingleProduct = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntity");
              PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
              pi.setName("product_id");
              pi.setValue(Integer.parseInt(Products[0][0]));
              pi.setType(Integer.class);
              SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

              pi = new PropertyInfo();
              pi.setName("sku");
              pi.setValue(Products[0][1]);
              pi.setType(String.class);
              SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

              pi = new PropertyInfo();
              pi.setName("qty");
              pi.setValue(Products[0][2]);
              pi.setType(Double.class);
              SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

              SoapObject EntityArray = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
              EntityArray.addProperty("products",SingleProduct);


              request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
              //adding the propery such as sessionId and Customerdata for request
              request.addProperty("sessionId",sessionId );
              request.addProperty("quoteId",100);
              request.addProperty("products",EntityArray);
              request.addProperty("options",null);
              request.addProperty("bundle_option",null);
              request.addProperty("bundle_option_qty",null);
              request.addProperty("links",null);         
              //request.addProperty("store_id", 1);
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              transport.call(NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
              //getting the response which is the customerId
              Log.d("Test", "request: " + transport.requestDump);
              Log.d("Test", "response: " + transport.responseDump);
               }

                 catch (IOException e)
                      {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                      } 
                 catch (XmlPullParserException e)
                      {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**shoppingCartProductAdd** method having only 4 parameters
sessionId,
quoteId,
products\productsData ,
storeId (optional)

, but your sending more then that, so remove

```
 request.addProperty("options",null);
 request.addProperty("bundle_option",null);
 request.addProperty("bundle_option_qty",null);
 request.addProperty("links",null);
```

from your code and try.

You can add these properties to the **shoppingCartProductEntity** methods if you want.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html for more details